# Subtract Minutes and Hours from UTC timestamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a UNIX timestamp I need to calculate time interval from it. Example if UNIXTIMESTAMP says it has 5:48 pm the time interval = 5 pm to 6pm. I am trying to subtract minutes, and seconds from the UNIX timestamp but did not find any proper values.Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: Can you show some code of what you're trying? What's not working? What is it doing vs what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` object provides lots of utility functions; no need to try and deal with the minutes. Try this:

```
function interval(date) {
  var hour = date.getHours();

  return [hour, hour + 1];
}

// right now it's 7:06pm
interval(new Date()); // => [19, 20];
```

**Edit**

If you want to get a range of timestamps, you can do something like this:

```
function interval(date) {
  var low = date.getTime() - (date.getMinutes() * 60000);
  var high = low + 3600000;

  return [low, high];
}

function isBetween(time, range) {
  return time > range[0] && time < range[1];
}

var myInterval = interval(new Date()); // => [1441479617237, 1441483217237];

var isBetweenMyInterval = isBetween(1441480944720, myInterval); // => true
```

Comment: !! wonderful :) Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks But i need to convert it back into UTC timestamp

Comment: @Priya you want each number in the range to be in milliseconds since epoch, or a date time stamp?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am getting a timestamp as an input which is epoch Timestamp. I have to get the current time e.g :7:55pm get the range 7 to 8 convert it back to Epoch then check if the Timestamp received is within in the range. Since the Timestamp Received is Epoch format eg: 1441423141 it has day date associated with it, so now when i have to check  if it is in today's current time interval. Sorry for the confusion, I am stuck since long time.

Comment: @Priya, I've edited my answer to provide another algorithm. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: it worked. I have question though why did you multiplied minutes by 60000 ? Is it conversion from local to UTC ?? @Josh Thanks

Comment: @Priya, `getMinutes` returns a number between 0 and 60. But, we want that in milliseconds. There are 60 seconds per minute, and 1000 milliseconds per second, so 60*1000 is 60000. It's just a conversion from minutes to milliseconds.

Comment: ok cool !! Similarly if i have to go to start of the day I would subtract the hours converting it into milliseconds ? Hope it's correct!! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert your Unix Time stamp to Date Object in JavaScript using :

```
var dt = new Date(UNIX_TIMESTAMP*1000)
```

Then you can get what you need from the Date object.

Comment: Thanks @sambhav gore :)